# How to use $_Files when we are with HTTPS protocol

Tags: php, file-upload, https

I'm trying to upload a file on the serveur it works when i am in http context but when i try it on a https one it doesn't work. any ideas plz?

Comment: Switching to HTTPS should not have any impact on the use of `$_FILES`

Comment: Is it possible your HTTPS is running the same PHP loaded from the same php.ini as the http version? (some hosts separate these)

Comment: unfortunately it has the script is not working any more

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you check that the server you're uploading to supports HTTPS, it could be that it doesn't listen to HTTPS requests, or that it is set up to handle HTTPS requests completely differently (i.e. a different document root when compared to the http document root of the site you're trying to access).

If this is a local development server, make sure you have HTTPS enabled and a HTTPS VHost that works and uses the correct VHost.